# Using Bison/Lex with a Grammar

Tags: bison, lex

I've been tasked to develop a Parser/Interpreter for a language called Uoladixs, a language our professor made up himself. We've been provided a grammar for Uoladixs as well as a description of the Uoladixs tokens. We are required to use lex and bison and I have never used either before.

How exactly are the three related and what do you feed the lex and bison commands and what comes out?

Essentially, I am in need of a Lex/Bison 101 course. Any text suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Just rolls off the tongue, that language name ;)

Comment: Is Bison every used *without* a grammar?

Comment: My money is on an anagram for "A Loud Six".

Answer (score 0):

This book might help you:  [flex & bison](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155972)